# Context switches on iOS using "performSelectorOnMainThread"

Tags: ios, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, critical-section

I have weird threading issues on iOS. Consider a simple method like this:

```
- (BOOL)doSomething
{
   [self doA];
   [self doB];
}
```

This method should *only* run in context of the main thread. I need to call this method from a worker thread. I use `performSelectorOnMainThread` for this purpose.

If I do everything as explained here. Can a context switch happen between `doA` and `` `doB ``?

(I don't think so, I just want to make sure that my understanding is right here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "context switch" I assume you mean the main thread switching to some other main thread event (as you could always switch to another worker thread at any time).

However, main thread will finish all of doSomething before doing anything else.

Excerpt from [performSelectorOnMainThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method queues the message on the run loop of the main thread
>   using the common run loop modes—that is, the modes associated with the
>   NSRunLoopCommonModes constant. **As part of its normal run loop
>   processing, the main thread dequeues the message (assuming it is
>   running in one of the common run loop modes) and invokes the desired
>   method.** Multiple calls to this method from the same thread cause the
>   corresponding selectors to be queued and performed in the same same
>   order in which the calls were made.